# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str. While testing in POSTMAN

Tags: python, json, api, rest

**I am trying to run the POST method from POSTMAN while testing, but I am receiving some error and I couldn't find any solution.**

here's the code for the app in python:

here I created list of stores:

```
stores = [
            {
                'name':'Mart',
                'items':[{'name':'Item1','price':120}]
            }
    ]
```

#### POST - used to receive data

#### GET - used to send data back only

Creating endpoint for homepage:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Creating endpoint for creating a new store:

```
# POST /store data: {name:}
@app.route('/store', methods=['POST'])
def create_store():
    request_data = request.get_json()
    new_store = {
            'name':request_data['name'],
            'items':[]
        }
    stores.append(new_store)
    return jsonify(new_store)
```

Creating endpoint for getting a specific store:

```
# GET /store/<string: name>
    # 'hppt://127.0.0.1:5000/store/some_name
@app.route('/store/<string:name>')   
def get_store(name):
    # iterate over stores
    for store in stores:
        # if the store name matches, return it
        if store['name'] == name:
            return jsonify(store)
    # if none match, return an error message
    return jsonify({'ERROR': 'Store Not Found!'})
```

Creating endpoint for getting all the stores

```
# GET /store
@app.route('/store')   
def get_stores():
    return jsonify({'stores':stores})
```

Creating endpoint for creating items in specific store:

```
# POST /store/<string: name>/item {name:, price:}
@app.route('/store/<string:name>/item',methods=['POST'])   
def create_items_in_store(name):
    request_data = request.get_json()
    for store in stores:
        if store['name'] == name:
            new_item = {
                    'name': request_data['name'],
                    'price': request_data['price']
                }
            stores['items'].append(new_item)
            return jsonify(new_item)
    return jsonify({'ERROR': 'Item could not be added!'})
```

Creating endpoint for getting items from specific store:

```
# GET /store/<string: name>/item
@app.route('/store/<string:name>/item')   
def get_items_in_store(name):
    for store in stores:
        if store['name'] == name:
            return jsonify({'items': store['items']})
    return jsonify({'ERROR': 'Item Not Found in Store!'})
```

Running the app on Port: 5000

```
app.run(port=5000)
```

**POSTMAN:**

```
URL:'http://127.0.0.1:5000/store/Mart/item'
```

And the **POST** request is:

```
{
    "name":"peanuts",
    "price": 340
}
```

The **Error** I am receiving is:

```
File "e:\Courses\Online_Practice\REST_API\01_First_REST_API\app.py", line 64, in create_items_in_store
    stores['items'].append(new_item)
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code

```
for store in stores:
    if store['name'] == name:
        new_item = {
                'name': request_data['name'],
                'price': request_data['price']
            }
        stores['items'].append(new_item)
```

On the last line, you're modifying the `stores` which based on the error and the code, is a list, not the dictionary `store`.
You probably want to do `store['items'].append(new_item)`

Comment: @VishwasBasotra Please accept the answer if it solves your problem. Next time, pay more attention to the error message, it can usually tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```py
    for store in stores:
        if store['name'] == name:
            new_item = {
                    'name': request_data['name'],
                    'price': request_data['price']
                }
            stores['items'].append(new_item)
```

The problem is that `stores` is your array of all stores, which is a list of dictionaries. And the elements of a name are not named, you can only access them with indices.

Try this instead:

```py
    for index, store in enumerate(stores):
        if store['name'] == name:
            new_item = {
                    'name': request_data['name'],
                    'price': request_data['price']
                }
            stores[index].append(new_item)
```

Comment: I can't answer @'Thu Yein Tun's answer directly, because I have not enough reputation so I will ask here. Are you sure the given solution works? I think it only fixes the type error, but the program still not runs as indented.